# Injective/Surjection/Bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

[image]

How would you handle the h(x) case to see if it is surjective or injective? Also, how would you prove/disprove that it is a bijection. I know you have to show if it is injective and surjective, but I dont know how given the h(x) case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are countably infinite many natural numbers, and only two elements in $\{0, 1\}$, so no bijection exists. If you haven't yet learned, you will learn that a bijection between two sets exists if and only if they have the same cardinality.

We can show this explicitly:

**Surjective?**  Since there are both even and odd numbers in $\mathbb N$, both $0$ and $1$ will each have elements in $\mathbb N$ mapped to them. For example $h(2) = 0$ and $h(3) = 1$, so $h(x)$ IS surjective.

So if not bijective but surjective, we know that $h(x)$ must fail to be injective.

**Injective?** To prove explicitly that $h(x)$ is not injective, note that $h(2) = h(4) = 0$, but $2\neq 4$. So we know that at least two elements (indeed, infinitely many elements in $\mathbb N$) will be mapped to one element: $0$. (The same is true of the element $1 \in \{0, 1\}$. So $h(x)$ is not injective.